# What's the best way to deal with JAX-WS proxy objects for EJB JPA entities that are Lazy Loaded?

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, ejb, jax-ws

Unfortunately we are stuck using JPA 1.0 and Java EE 5 (SAP implementation). If it matters, we are using an Oracle DB.

We have an entity class that is basically a database description for a file type object, holding the name, file type and a byte[] (blob) item.

When calling a lookup on the the table we don't want to eagerly load the blob object every time, and return it through the web service, however we still want to load the file name and type fields.

Now, we've tried several things:-

Firstly, we've tried the `@Basic(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)`. This doesn't seem to do anything anyway. (Probably this is not an enforced JPA protocol)

Secondly we've tried making a one to one relationship with the byte data in a separate table, and setting that as a lazy fetch type. When doing this, this is when the exception occurs in the web service, because the Jax WS proxy object for this item is pretty much empty.

Thirdly, we've tried eagerly loading the entire "File" table, but then just blanking out the byte[] data after the database query; this doesn't return the large byte data over the web service, but it is not ideal as the byte data is still retrieved from the data into the program "context".

So is there a way to tell Jax WS to ignore a specific field, if the proxy object is empty? I couldn't seem to find anything in the documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a separate jax-ws type like "FileMetadata" which contains only the name and type fields?

Comment: Ok, so create a DTO for the file? Right now we are returning the parent entity which has one to many files (amongst other numerous fields). We'd probably need to create a transient field in the parent object for the DTO class in order to return all the required items. So it's definitely a possibility to do it this way (if i've understood what you mean by jax-ws type). Is there however a more elegant way, that doesn't involve polluting the parent entity class (we could create another DTO object holding the entity class and the file class to return too).

Comment: @Davos555 - frankly, this is why many people advocate separating your DTOs from your entities.  how you choose to model the data often differs--sometimes dramatically--from how you want to transmit the data remotely.